# Memory layout of executable

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

When loading an executable then segments like the code, data, bss and so on need to be placed in memory. I am just wondering, if someone could tell me where on a standard x86 for example the libc library is placed. Is that at the top or bottom of memory. My guess is at the bottom, close to the application code, ie., that would look something like this here:

```
---------  0x1000
Stack
  |
  V

  ^
  |
Heap
----------
Data + BSS
----------

App Code

----------

libc

---------- 0x0000
```

Thanks a lot,
Ross

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the whims of the loader.

In particular, on any modern system that uses [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), you can't predict where a particular library is going to end up.

Comment: sure, but it is a possiblity that the loader places it at the low end of the memory. I assume that the stack is fixed at the top of the memory and grows down, whereas the heap comes next that grows up. But not sure about the other segments.

Comment: @Ross: If it was "always" put at the bottom of memory, that would defeat the point of any randomization, and make a return-to-libc attack trivial. Additionally, your assumptions are pretty unfounded - processes can have numerous threads, and each thread has its own stack. If you're interested in a particular system, ask about that system - there is no general answer.